# How to exit from this view mode in Altium!

Tags: pcb, altium

There are so many shortcut keys in Altium. I entered this view mode without noticing what keys I stroked, just can't exit from this view mode :(.

[image]

Comment: How about you try Holding down Ctrl key with left click.   Ctrl+left click somewhere outside. You'll resume with all the layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is *Single Layer* mode. Try Shift+S.

Comment: Yes, Shift+S can toggle on/off this mode. Thanks!!!

Comment: It's a very useful mode to use in layout. Other escapes from unwanted modes include hitting the clear button in the lower right corner to clear selection filters, and View-> Desktop Layouts-> Default when your workspace layout gets messed up.